# Shutting down Selenium without closing the browser, while cleaning up temporary files

Tags: java, selenium

I have a set of classes written in Java using Selenium WebDriver for automating various tasks on a number of different websites such as logging in and fetching data.

From time to time we would need to access the page ourselves to find something, and the process of logging in manually is pretty...well, boring and a waste of time.

I figured since we already have the login macro, why don't we just let selenium handle it.

I would like to open a new browser, do the login procedures, and then shut down selenium. The user would then resume whatever tasks they wanted to do on the site.

I've noticed that if I don't properly shut down Selenium, it leaves an anonymous profile in the temp folder. Overtime, I've accumulated about a gig's worth of profiles before I realized this was happening. Turns out it was because I wasn't properly shutting down selenium using `close` and `quit`

However, if I use those methods, the browser is closed with it. Just now I have tested as follows

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.close()  // shuts down the browser
```

Then I tried

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.quit() // shuts down the browser
```

Is there a way for me to shut down Selenium without closing the browser while cleaning up all these anonymous profiles? I'm basically using it as a macro, except I launch it programmatically through our Java application that manages all the different macros.

Comment: Let me rephrase your question: you want to connect to already opened browser window with new Selenium test to avoid logging in, right? Then it is not possible for Selenium, see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18

Comment: @olyv I would like to open a new browser, do the login procedures, and then shut down selenium since it has finished its job. The user would then resume whatever tasks they wanted to do on the site.

Comment: you should do it in an other tab swtich do your stuff and close the tab and continue:
Set<String> winSet = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
List<String> winList = new ArrayList<String>(winSet);
String newTab = winList.get(winList.size() - 1);
//webDriver.close(); // close the original tab
webDriver.switchTo().window(newTab); // switch to new tab

Comment: @Csanesz I opened a new window and then executed the procedures in the new window. I then switched to the old window and closed it. However, selenium is still running (just waiting in the background). I told it to `quit()` and then it just closed all of the browsers.

Comment: The 'browser' that Selenium is opening is a driver browser exclusively.  If you try to shut down Selenium, you are shutting down the driver and therefore the 'browser' as well.  This is a limitation of WebDriver and I don't see a way for you to get your desired results this way, sorry.

Comment: Please, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

After your code is done, kill the executable process and then exit the program without driver.quit()

```
    try{
    /*kill the process*/
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    /*Exit*/
    System.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just quit the program while leaving the browser intact. Assuming you have a console application:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: But this doesn't close the driver resources - geckodriver.exe stays running. Every time you run this program, another geckodriver.exe process is started.